# Finding missing variables in a mustache template

Tags: mustache

I have a a textarea which are compile with Mustachejs together with a json object into html. It works as intended but I would like some debugging information if there are variables that are undefined. For instance if I have

```
var data = { "totle" : "My cool page"}; // Noticed the misspelled name
<h3>{{title}}</h3>
```

it would result in an empty h3 tag. I would, somehow, like to get information that "title" is undefined, is this possible?

Comment: Some Mustache implementations allow for that. Check for example https://github.com/groue/GRMustache/blob/master/Guides/delegate.md#default-values: you can log messages like `Missing value for <GRMustacheVariableTag `{{ name }}` at line 3>`

Comment: Thank you, will look into it, seems promising.

Comment: The link I gave you is not a link to a javascript implementation of Mustache. But you may ask for the feature to be added to the https://github.com/janl/mustache.js/ repository.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up writing the logic myself sort of. The renderTokens method in mustache.js is where the lookup is made. I make checks  in the switch to look for values which are undefined if they are I store the tokenValue in a global array which I can present as the result of all undefined values.